# jQuery fadein fade out collapsable grid

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a collapsable grid which fades in and  out when ever user click on a link.
the problem is that when ever user clicks on the link multiple times very quickly,,multiple grids open and do not fade out..this problem is only seen in Firefox   not in IE.

Answer (score 2):

If the previous animation hasn't finished, you could get this problem. Make sure you stop previous animations. For example:

```
$("a.mylink").click(function() {
  $("#somediv").stop().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

The key here is [`stop()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop).